# active item li on menu where hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="topbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="nav-quote-button">Get Quote</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**How to set class Active on li 2,3,4... where hover, and remove class active has a go**

Thank you!

Comment: People, you are all downvoting but you are not saying why. Let him/her know what they did wrong.

Comment: Question shows a lack of research try looking in jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This isn't a request website, this is for people interested in programming and submitting legitimate questions interested in learning why the source code/attempt didn't work and understanding why and how to fix it.

Comment: I see that you are new here at OS. anyways , to save your reputation make sure you post real questions , just by googling your issue you will see tons of answers. like http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_menu.asp

Comment: I can't believe what I've seen 4 insta down vote at the same time :'D

Comment: @TranBinh , Dude, what have you tried so far. We can help you, but show us what you have tried, and we can take it from there. If you dont show us what you tried than people will downvote.This can be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need it to be active for some kind of query down the line (I personally don't know why you would, though), try CSS.

```
li:hover {
     //  Active class CSS here
}
```

You can add further selectors to the li to keep yourself from selecting other lists on the page, and it doesn't take any JavaScript, JQuery, or fancy coding.

The :hover psuedo-selector will make it where it applies the CSS to the element that you're hovering over.

Comment: I want the active class is not lost, just hover your mouse on the other li New Item lost.  sample menu:  http://www.lazada.vn/?setLang=en